# Percentile for a value

Tags: javascript

Given an array of numbers, I am looking to find the percentile of a given value.

I found this code here that seems to do what I need, but I was hoping I could get someone to explain this code to me step by step:

```
const percentile = (arr, val) =>
  (100 *
    arr.reduce(
      (acc, v) => acc + (v < val ? 1 : 0) + (v === val ? 0.5 : 0),
      0
    )) /
  arr.length;

// example
// percentile([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 6); // 55
```

---

**Update**

Thanks everyone for your help. I found a Percentile formula that further helps me understand what the code is doing.

Formula:

**Percentile = [L + ( 0.5 x S ) / N] * 100**

- L = Number of below rank
- S = Number of same rank
- N = Total numbers

Based on my new understanding of the function, I find this a bit easier to read:

```js
/**
 * **Percentile = ((L + ( 0.5 x S )) / N) * 100**
 * - L = Number of values **lower** than `value`
 * - S = Number of same rank
 * - N = Total numbers
 */
const percentile = (arr, value) => {
  const currentIndex = 0;
  const totalCount = arr.reduce((count, currentValue) => {
    if (currentValue < value) {
      return count + 1; // add 1 to `count`
    } else if (currentValue === value) {
      return count + 0.5; // add 0.5 to `count`
    }
    return count + 0;
  }, currentIndex);
  return (totalCount * 100) / arr.length;
};
```

Comment: No, it does not assume that the array is sorted.

Comment: Which part of it don't you understand? Do you know how `array.reduce()` works?

Comment: It's simply counting the number of array elements that are less than `val`. Then it divides the count by the number of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is equivalent to ths simpler version.

`count` contains the number of elements that `val` is higher than, plus 0.5 for each element it's equal to. Dividing this total by the number of elements is the percentile.

```js
const percentile = (arr, val) => {
  let count = 0;
  arr.forEach(v => {
    if (v < val) {
      count++;
    } else if (v == val) {
      count += 0.5;
    }
  });
  return 100 * count / arr.length;
}

console.log(percentile([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 6));
```

Comment: @letie Don't use `map()` if you don't need the resulting array. There's nothing at that site that compares `map()` with `forEach()`. All the comparisons are between functions and `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the vector is not sorted the result is correct. The vector can contain duplicated values.

*reduce* scan a vector and produce a result accumulating partial results inside the *acc*

*acc* is initialized to 0 (line 5)

*(v < val ? 1 : 0)*  result in 1 or 0 depending if v < val. The conditional ternary operator *? :*  is not needed because *true* is interpreted as 1 and *false* as 0, so you can write only  *+ (v < val)*

*(v === val ? 0.5 : 0)* add .5 only for values equal to the *val*.

Lines 2 and 7 transform the frequency of lower (and equal) values into a percentile.

Answer (score 0):

#### Step-by-step explanation

1. A constant named "percentile" is defined and passes two arguments, an array "arr" and a value "val", to the given function...
2. The reduce() method is called on the array. This takes a function as an argument (called a reducer function), as well as an optional argument *initialValue*, which is defined here as 0 (zero).
3. The reducer function creates an empty number variable "acc". The variable "v" refers to the current value, as taken from the array "arr".
4. The reduce method iterates through each value in `arr` (aka it sets each element in `arr` as `v`). On each iteration...
5. The reducer function compares `v` to `val`. If `v` is less than `val`, then `acc` is increased by 1. If `v` is equal to `val`, then `acc` is increased by 0.5. (In layperson's terms, this means that as the function iterates through each element in `arr`, the value of `acc` is counting how many elements are less than or equal to `val`.)
6. After the function has iterated through every element of the array, `acc` is divided by the number of elements in `arr`. (In other words, since `acc` is the number of elements that are less than `val`, dividing `acc`/`arr` gives us a decimal representing the proportion of the array that's less than `val`.)
7. That number is multiplied by 100 to turn the decimal into a percentage.